# DB2 Error SQLERRMC: DOUBLE

Tags: sql, database, db2, sqlcode

I am trying to run a query from my program, I am getting the below error message when I checked my logs, please provide me a solution/suggestion.

```
com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.SqlException: DB2 SQL error: SQLCODE: -420, SQLSTATE: 22018, SQLERRMC: DOUBLE
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.hh.b(hh.java:1369)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.hh.c(hh.java:1356)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.db.k(db.java:352)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.db.a(db.java:60)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.t.a(t.java:52)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.c.tb.b(tb.java:202)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.ih.ab(ih.java:1898)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.ih.d(ih.java:2467)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.ih.W(ih.java:525)
        at com.ibm.db2.jcc.b.ih.executeUpdate(ih.java:508)
        at com.test.internal.updateImp.updateRow(updateImp.java:**107**)
```

Code:

```
public int updateRow(String jobID ,Connection connect) throws Exception{
    int cnt =0;     
    Statement  stmt = null;
    try {
        stmt = connect.createStatement();
        String query = dbConnection.UPDATE_EMPLOYEE.toString();
        query = query.replace("?", jobID);  //line 107      
        cnt = stmt.executeUpdate(query);
    } catch (Exception ex) {
         ex.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try{                
            if(stmt != null) stmt.close();              
        }catch(Exception ex){
             ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return cnt;     
}
```

Query is

```
UPDATE INTRA.EMPLOYEE SET STATUS = 'Y' WHERE JOB_ID IN (?)
```

Comment: SO is not a replacement for looking up error codes.  Did you *try* searching for "DB2 SQLCODE -420" before posting this question?

Comment: You may want to print out the actual SQL statement just before `executeUpdate()`. And consider reading about `PreparedStatement` and the proper use of parameter markers.

Comment: Thank you all for the suggestions, actually the problem was with some privileges.  I changed the permissions to read/write and it got cleared.